# How to write this javascript without using apostrophes

Tags: javascript, encoding, mybb

I'm trying to get a line of flags wiht google translate on my site. This other site already has it, but it uses blogger API. I changed the JS accordingly, but I found out that my forum software encodes de apostrophe as \'

Is there any way I can write the same html+js below without using apostrophes?

```
<a  target="_blank" rel="nofollow"  
onclick="window.open('http://www.google.com/translate?u='+encodeURIComponent(document.URL)+'&langpair=pt%7Czh-CN&hl=pt&ie=UTF8'); return false;"
title="Google-Translate-Chinese (Simplified) BETA"><img  style="border: 0px solid ; cursor: pointer; width: 24px; height: 24px;"
alt="Google-Translate-Chinese" src="http://lh5.ggpht.com/_mcq01yDJ2uY/Sdke4C8za2I/AAAAAAAAAkU/Mpfn_ntCweU/China.png"
title="Google-Translate-Chinese">
```

As it is, the forum engine translates it as ""window.open(\'http://www.google.com/translate?u=\'+"

Comment: Maybe using `\"` instead of apostrophe `'` can help you?

Answer (score 1):

Try using something like this

```
onclick="window.open(\"http://www.google.com/translate?u=\"+encodeURIComponent
(document.URL)+\"&langpair=pt%7Czh-CN&hl=pt&ie=UTF8\"); return false;"
```

Since you are already using escape string, your forum engine might not replace this with another '\'.